# Join produces duplicated key (column) in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, teradata, volatile

In Teradata SQL I have two volatile tables that I would like to join. However, if I join them on colA, they both show up in the output. I just want this colA once in the output, not twice.

So I have:

```
Table1 with colA, colB, colC
Table2 with colA, colD, colE
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.colA = Table2.colA
```

gives me: `colA, colB, colC, colA, colD, colE`

while I would like to have: `colA, colB, colC, colD, colE`

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: `select table1.colA, table1.colB, table1.colC, table2.colD, table2.colE from ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to explicitly choose the columns you want -- with qualified names:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t2.D, t2.E
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.colA = t2.colA;
```

The ANSI syntax has the `USING` clause which does allow you to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2
     USING (colA);
```

I don't believe Teradata supports this clause.